# Google App Index Api to promote App?

Tags: android, google-search, android-developer-api, android-app-indexing, google-search-platform

Will implementing the App Index API help improve the visibility of my app while using Google Search if it is not yet installed on a device\tablet? Considering that my app does not have any related website content to display.

I just want my app to be more visible to users searching for certain specific keywords e.g. 'recipes', 'wifis' etc.

Here is the API i am talking about. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aISUYHTkTOU

In the video they do say that they have discovered new apps, apart from re-engaging with the old ones  but does not say how.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

App Indexing associates your app with urls, either website urls or custom-scheme urls that refer to content that your app displays. So if you have content in your app that you can define custom urls for (like android-app://my.package.name/...), then even if the content is not on a website, you can implement app indexing and have that content show up in Google search results (along with a prompt to install your app if they don't have it installed.)

However, if you don't have any content that your app displays, then app indexing won't help you. It's not a general tool to put your app in search results unrelated to your content.